# Searching in nested arrays Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

> I have a mongodb with some JSON data which includes and nested arrays. I am
>   trying to make a query to count how many documents have a specific
>   value. For example here is how my json data looks:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5ecb815bf4b8512918224e71"),
    "array1" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ecb815bf4b8512918224e85"),
            "xxxx" : "1450",
            "yyyy" : 83,
            "array2" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5ecb815bf4b8512918224e88"),
                    "aaaa" : "1470420945276",

                }, 
                {...},
                {...}]
}
```

> The query that i am trying is the following:

```
db.example.aggregate([
            {
               $project: {
                  value1: {
                     $filter: {
                        input: "$array1",
                        as: "array",
                        cond: { $eq: [ "$$array.array2.aaaa" , "1470420945276" ] }
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               $project: {
                  value1Count: { $size: "$value1" }
               }
            }
         ])
```

> But doesnt work and returns that value1Count=0. It looks like it doesnt nnavigate into the array2 to
>   read the value of the 'aaaa'. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost close to getting the desired value. The problem is `$$array.array2.aaaa` returns an `array` value, so we can't use `$eq` here. Instead, we should use `$in` operator.

```
db.example.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      value1: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$array1",
          as: "array",
          cond: {
            $in: [
              "1470420945276",
              "$$array.array2.aaaa"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      value1Count: {
        $size: "$value1"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eTtcCzi644U) | [Alternative solution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tZt8t8IoHPP)

Comment: Yes it works fine. I am a little bit confused about how it works. If i have to navigate it into a subnested array i have to do the same ? cond: {
            $in: [
              "1470420945276",
              "$$array.array2.array3.aaaa"
            ]
          }

Comment: i have the same problem with extra subnested arrays, so i am trying ti unserstand better how it works.

Comment: @ZimR No. You can only take only 1 nested array per level (`$$array.array2`, `$$array2.array3`, so on...) Check my alternative solution, you need to go down with `$filter` for each array.

Comment: So i have to use an extra $filter in the $project and as an input put the value1?

Comment: @ZimR What is your use case?

Comment: sorry my friend i just see your alternative solution. I will try it

Comment: I saw your alternative solution. It's almost looks like my db but in my db before the example there is an object Id. So when i put the id before the example array still not working.. You could take a look : [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yQLQInm8X94).

Comment: @ZimR You had a wrong mongodb configuration, take a look now [https://mongoplayground.net/p/tZt8t8IoHPP](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tZt8t8IoHPP)